# Plugin system with MVC3, Razor and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm fairly decent with MVC3 and enjoy creating my sites with it, however, I am yet to think up and implement a decent method of a "plugin" system.

Basically, I aim to have a generic "blog-type" CMS which I can distribute across my sites, but with the option to have certain things as plugins.

For example:

Generic build:

- User area
- Basic blog/news editing

Plugins: (May be needed for one or two sites, but not all)

- Chatroom plugin
- Stats
- and so on...

Currently I would just make it all and disable things through a config file, however it would be nice if i could just drop a folder into my FTP and have an MVC page which automatically picks it up!

I assume I would have to start with scanning the directory "/plugins" and picking up a "plugin.config" (Or similar) file which would contain the basic details.

But how would I get my main system to pick these things up and actually use them?!

Comment: Did you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340183/plug-in-architecture-for-asp-net-mvc

Comment: How did this not come up in my original search! Fantastic stuff!

Comment: making a plugin architecture has been something I have tried with ASP.NET and latterly with ASP.NET MVC - it is _always_ a PITA - tread carefully and try to sense the PITA before you spend too long on it :)

Comment: Have you conisdered using a CMS that *already* supports plugins? For example, Orchard: http://www.orchardproject.net/

Comment: I did but due to the nature of the system, it would take longer to customize an existing CMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do this using MVC Areas, here are some links about them:

- [ASP.NET MVC 2 Areas](http://elegantcode.com/2010/03/13/asp-net-mvc-2-areas/)
- [ASP.NET MVC Areas: Are they important to a large application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462458/asp-net-mvc-areas-are-they-important-to-a-large-application)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462458/asp-net-mvc-areas-are-they-important-to-a-large-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841520/asp-net-mvc-areas-how-can-i-use-them)

Answer (score 2):

Try assembly scanning with StructureMap dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

Read this great tutorial: [ASP.NET MVC2 Plugin Architecture Tutorial](http://fzysqr.com/2010/04/26/asp-net-mvc2-plugin-architecture-tutorial/)

It help me create a plugin architecture with MVC3.

Answer (score 1):

Areas solve the problem for you providing you have everything in the original project/assembly. You could write your plugin system to allow the plugins to register their own areas, or alternatively you could register some new view search paths in a custom Razor view engine.

I chose the latter for a recent OS project I wrote called [Spruce](http://spruce.codeplex.com/), which uses a whole plugin architecture you might find useful as a reference.

You can scan all the assemblies in the bin directory on startup to check for plugins, via reflection. You usually check for types that implement an interface or inherit from a class, and use these along side an IoC container such as TinyIoc, NInject, StructureMap or Unity. I'd recommend TinyIoC which is used by NancyFX.